# Сохранить фото Instagram, которые получает скрипт в переменную

Tags: javascript, instagram

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var userFeed = new Instafeed({
   get: 'user',
   userId: '1805227844',
   clientId: 'e9f1aeae68ed43c18c4a96b64038e78f',
   accessToken: '1805227844.e9f1aea.68a3fe3edcf548c08cb46093cd4c966b',
   resolution: 'standard_resolution',
   template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
   sortBy: 'most-recent',
   limit: 6,
   links: false
 });
 userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую скрипт `instafeed.js`. Он получает фото из Instagram и помещает их в блок с `id="instafeed"`.
Можно ли как-то эти фото сохранить сначала в какую-то переменную, чтобы потом помещать ее в блоки.

P.S: Нужно вставить эти фотки в трех местах на странице.

Comment: конечно можно. можно было бы открыть исходник Instafeed, вдохновится (там наверное строчек 50-100) и переписать как угодно

Comment: там 360, вот ваша функция: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/instafeed.js#L38

Comment: github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/… это функция исходника? всмысле как работает этот скрипт изнутри?